# Least repeating chararcter in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the least repeating character in a string ,it works for some input but it fails for some input.

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer> ();

    String s = "abcdabcdabcdacd";
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

    for (Character ch: chars) {
        if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
            map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }

    Set<Character> keys = map.keySet();

    for (Character ch: keys) {
        if (map.get(ch) ==1) {
            System.out.println(ch + " ");
        }
    }
```

I expect the output to be b but it doesn't show anything.
If i give aabaa as the input then it shows b and that's correct.

Comment: your problem is because of this condition: you don't print the char with the least occurences, only the char's with only one occurrence: if (map.get(ch) ==1)

Comment: What do you mean by “least repeating char?” The one that has the fewest number of occurrences? How does that explain “aabbcc” producing “abc”?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar because they all have the same number of occurrences

Comment: So you want to find the least repeating character**s**, plural. Why not create a frequency map, and do a second pass to find all keys with min values? Time complexity is O(n) in the worst case if all characters are unique.

Comment: To count occurrences, consider using `map.merge(ch, 1, Integer::sum)` instead of if-else

Comment: For future questions I would recommend waiting a bit longer then 20 minutes before accepting an answer so you can see all your options before taking the first one that comes along. I believe my answer is the most atomic one but not necessarily the best one, that is up to others to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented already, you only check for characters which only occur once, not for the least occurrence.

You can change your code by this:

```
public class PrintB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        String s = "abcdabcdabcdacd";
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

        for (Character ch: chars) {
            if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
                map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }

        Set<Character> keys = map.keySet();
        boolean broken = false;
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) { // the max will be s.length()

            for (Character ch : keys) {
                if (map.get(ch) == i) { // this amount is checked for each char
                    System.out.println(ch + " ");
                    broken = true;
                }
            }
            if ( broken ) {
                i = s.length(); // sure, there are other ways to break out of the loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: may be done as simple as `map.entrySet().stream().min( Comparator.comparingInt( Map.Entry::getValue ) ).get().getKey();` not requiring O(N^2) as in your solution

Comment: @AlexSalauyou yes, but considering the original code, the chance the OP understands this code to find his error, will be a lot bigger. Nothing in the original post suggests he knows how to work with streams, so why further confuse him?

Comment: @AlexSalauyou doesn't your code always return only a single character? From my understanding it should return all characters with the least occurances, eg.: for `aabbccdddd` it should return `abc`

Comment: @Amongalen you're right, I just show an approach to simplify

Answer (score 1):

Using streams you may simply do:

```
final String s = "abcdabcdabcdacd";

String leastRepeated = 
   s.chars().mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char) i))      // map to Stream<String>   
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> 1, Integer::sum))  // Map<String, Integer>
    .entrySet().stream()                                      // stream over map
    .min(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))               // comparing values in map
    .get().getKey();                                          // get resp entry
```

which outputs:

> b

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work the way you would want it to is because your last code block is only printing if the character is being repeated once and only once:

```
for (Character ch: keys) {
    if (map.get(ch) ==1) {
        System.out.println(ch + " ");
    }
```

However by using the `Collections.min` method we can find the lowest map value which we can then use to find the character it belongs to from map keys. Here is the complete code with context:

```
/**
 * @return an array of Character objects that have occured the
 * least amount of times in the given {@code String} parameter.
 * <i>Note that all whitespaces found within the {@code String} will be ignored </i>
 */
public static Character[] getLeastRepeatingCharacters(String text) {

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer> ();
    /*
     * Remove all whitespaces from the text as we don't
     * want to include them in our comparison oprations
     */
    text = text.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    for (Character ch : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
            map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
        }
        else if (ch != '\0') {
            map.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }
    /*
     * Get map value that occurs the least amount of times
     */
    int leastOccuranceValue = Collections.min(map.values());
    java.util.List<Character> leastOccurances = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    /*
     * Iterate through the map, find all characters that have
     * occured the least amount of times and add them to a list
     */
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(leastOccuranceValue)) {
            leastOccurances.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return leastOccurances.toArray(new Character[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "abcdabcdabcdacd";
    Character[] leastRepeating = getLeastRepeatingCharacters(text);

    String log = "Array of charactes that repeated the least amount of times in text '%s':%n%s";
    System.out.printf(log, text, Arrays.toString(leastRepeating));
}
```

**Output:**

Your string sample:

```
Array of charactes that repeated the least amount of times in text 'abcdabcdabcdacd ':
[b]
```

String sample provided by Stultuske:

```
Array of charactes that repeated the least amount of times in text 'kambcxdabcdalbcdacd ':
[x, k, l, m]
```

Comment: how does this meet the OP's requirements? it prints them all, not just the ones that occur the least

Comment: My apologies, I've updated my answer to include full code.

Comment: Your code still has serious flaws. add a few characters that only occur once, and it 'll still only print the x.: Character x repeated the least amount of times in text kambcxdabcdalbcdacd

Comment: Thank you for the correction, it should work properly now and return a proper array of `Character` objects. Though it doesn't matter as the OP is far gone by this point, but it's still a decent exercise for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the whole map to get the min occurrence, so you can't print in the loop, you should instead collect chars with min occurence, and then print them.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        String s = "abcdaybcdabcdacdz";
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

        for (Character ch: chars) {
            if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
                map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }

        List<Character> reps = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer count = chars.length;
        Set<Entry<Character, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet();
        for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : entries) {
            Integer n = entry.getValue();
            Character c = entry.getKey();
            if(n==count) {
                reps.add(c);
            }else if (n<count) {
                reps = new ArrayList<>();
                reps.add(c);
                count = n;
            }
        }

        for (Character character : reps) {
            System.out.println(character);
        }

    }
```